# On Chern classes of bundles on $\mathbb P^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be a globally generated vector bundle bundle of rank $r$ on $\mathbb P^n$. Then there exists a S.E.S: $0 \to K \to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}^{\oplus N} \to E \to 0$. Then is it necessarily true:

$(i)$ $c_1(E) \geq 0$?

Is this because restricting to a line $0 \to K|_L \to \mathcal O_{L}^{\oplus N} \to E|_L \to 0$ (why is this sequence exact?). Thus $E|_L$ is globally generated and on $L$ it splits as $E|_L \cong \oplus \mathcal O_{L}(a_i)$. Since $\mathcal O_L(a_i)$ are globally generated(?) and hence $a_i \geq 0$. Therefore $c_1(E)= c_1(E|_L) \geq0$. (Please correct me if this is wrong)

$(ii)$ Is there a way to realize that if $c_1(E)= \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)$, then either $E \cong \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1) \oplus \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}^{\oplus r-1}$ or $E \cong T_{\mathbb P^n}(-1) \oplus \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}^{r-n}$

Any suggestion indicating a brief proof is welcome. Note that, assuming $(i)$, one can show that if $c_1(E)=0$, then for every line $L$ in $\mathbb P^n$ $E|_L$ is trivial. But in that case as well I'm not sure why is $E$ trivial?

Comment: For a vector bundle, the first chern class is the same as the first chern class of its determinant. This should answer your first question.

Comment: @Mohan, $0= c_1(E) + c_1( K)$, why $c_1(K)$ can't be positive? Is it because it is a subsheaf of the trivial bundle?... and is there a reference ( with a proof) for the second question?

Comment: Did you look into the book of Okonek, Schneider and Spindler? This is a very rich source of information of that sort.